# Behavior change in py.exe on recent versions of Python for Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my Python scripts I use the shebang syntax at the beginning of the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

I noticed that this mostly stopped working recently (on Windows with Python 3.11 <s>and I believe also with 3.10.8</s>) - like there were some changes to py.exe.  When I run a script nothing happens:

```
# Nothing happens
myscript

# Nothing happens
myscript.py

# Nothing happens
py myscript.py
```

What's interesting is if I pass any options to py, then it works:

```
# Script invoked:
py -3 myscript.py
```

Also, if I change the shebang line to remove the 3 it works:

```py
# Change beginning of script to this:
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Now script runs
myscript

# Now script runs
myscript.py

# Now script runs
py myscript.py
```

If py.exe consistently didn't work with the /usr/bin/env python3 shebang I would think perhaps it was a change.  But since it works with any arguments, this makes me wonder if it's a bug?

Thoughts?

Updates:
Note:  The shebang syntax is officially supported for Python for Windows, please see:  https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

Further testing this out, I created the following test script - "myscript1.py":

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

print(f'Testing running using Python {sys.version}')
```

Results using Python 3.10 for Windows (64-bit version):

```
myscript1
Testing running using Python 3.10.8...
```

Results using Python 3.11 for Windows (64-bit version):

```
myscript1
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Results using Python 3.11 using python binary:

```
python myscript1.py
Testing running using Python 3.11.0...
```

Results using Python 3.11, call py launcher directly:

```
py myscript1.py
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Results using Python 3.10's py launcher directly:

```
py310 myscript1.py
Testing running using Python 3.11.0...
```

Results using Python 3.11's py launcher directly with any argument:

```
py -b myscript1.py
Testing running using Python 3.11.0...
```

If I edit myscript1.py and change the shebang line to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then it works:

```
myscript1
Testing running using Python 3.11.0...
```

So, it appears the py.exe launcher included with Python 3.11 does not work if the shebang line is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Unless an argument is passed - then it works.

This seems like a bug...

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, Windows have no proper `shebang line`. Shebang line normally used to say where executable is present/installed.

As per my observation

```
python3 - Linux 
python - Windows  or (python installed in linux <2.7)
```

1. This may be because Linux thought to keep different acronyms for differnt versions of python (Above 3+ -->`python3` & Below that use `python`
2. On `Windows`, where many of these facilities don't exist, a common arrangement is for `Python` to be installed in `C:\python3.1xx.xx\bin\Python.exe`

More observations

**windows**

```
where python
##Gives

C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

**Linux**

```
type -a python3

##Gives

usr/bin/env python3
```

So logically

for Linux -  `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

for windows - `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!python` (I always use this)

If you want to make `shebang` work on `windows` simply install `pywin32`. Logically it wont make work...But `pywin32` install some additional set of `modules` that helps to run `python` related exicutables smooth as which it acts as some API between python & windows

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Python for Windows officially supports the shebang line, please see https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines  Also, I tested more - this issue appears in Python 3.11.